# Why can I reach a different interface's IP address?

Tags: iptables, routing

I'm wondering about this, and I can't seem to find an explanation on the internet.
I have a linux gateway which has multiple interfaces:

```
eth0: external ip
eth1: 172.16.1.1/24
eth2: 172.16.2.1/24
ip_forward is enabled.
```

IPtables is configured to NAT traffic from `eth1 -> eth0` and `eth2 -> eth0`. But configured not to FORWARD traffic between `eth1 <-> eth2`.

My question is: Why is it possible for a computer on the 172.16.2.0/24 subnet to ping 172.16.1.1 (ip address of eth1 interface)?

**nat**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 647K packets, 52M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 17582 packets, 1160K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 14951 packets, 1214K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 187 packets, 42984 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 333K   25M SNAT       all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:<external ip>
```

**filter**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth2 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       <some trusted ip>       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth2  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth1  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth2  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ULOG       all  --  eth1  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW ULOG copy_range 0 nlgroup 1 prefix "NEW: " queue_threshold 1
    0     0 ULOG       all  --  eth2  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW ULOG copy_range 0 nlgroup 1 prefix "NEW: " queue_threshold 1
   0 0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   0 0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth2  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   0 0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth1   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   0 0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth2   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: I think you have to post your firewall config! Which rule have you already created and which default policy?

Comment: "Why would it not be possible?" is maybe a better question, or at least, why *you think* it shouldn't be.

Comment: Is it *only* the other router interface the inside legs can ping, or can they ping across the router to machines on the other leg, too?

Comment: @F.Hauri The default policy for INPUT is DROP, same for FORWARD. There is a rule to allow ping on the `eth1` and `eth2` interfaces
@goldilocks Well, I would think that you were unable to ping the ip address of different interface, because the ip isn't on the same network.
@WarrenYoung Yes, iptables drops traffic from `eth1` trying to reach `eth2`. So no pinging ie. `172.16.1.100
` from `172.16.2.100`.

Comment: Do this host have an `default gateway` rightly configured? If yes, this is the answer.

Comment: And I insist: If you want help, you **have** to post there your `iptable -t XX -nvL` for `XX` in all your actives tables!

Comment: @F.Hauri I added that to the original post (is there an easier way to format code without having to indent all lines with 4 spaces?). Also the default gw is the gateway on the external network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: Why is it possible for a computer on the 172.16.2.0/24 subnet to ping 172.16.1.1 (ip address of eth1 interface)?

Because you allowed it, and Linux does it by default.

Linux uses what is called a weak host model. That mean when it receives a packet coming from `eth2`, it will consider the packet to be for him if the destination address is an IP address of **any** of its interfaces, not only `eth2`'s. Even if forwarding is disabled.

So that packet enters the PREROUTING hook, the kernel then see that the destination address is its so proceed with the INPUT hook, and you accept all ICMP from `eth2`, so the packet is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You may *ping 172.16.2.0/24 subnet* from/to *172.16.1.1* while your firewall don't include ip based rules and you allow **all** traffic from both `eth1` *and* `eth2` to `eth0` (non ip based, including such redirect and back packets)

A good way is to explicitely **Drop** all packet related to local subnet ip:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -s 172.16.1.1/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -d 172.16.1.1/24 -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -s 172.16.2.1/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth2 -d 172.16.2.1/24 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

For sample, where `eth2` is linked to your *dmz* and `eth1` to *localnet*.

with this, you may by able to access `172.16.2.1/24` **from** `172.16.1.1/24`, but not in the other way!